# How to set more space between blocks Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My homepage consists of multiple blocks(top part/mid part/bottom part). I've created a row for each block. I want to add some space between my blocks in Bootstrap. Can I simply give my rows id's and add some margin, or is this wrong?

**Structure of my code:**

```
<div class="container" id="ho_main_content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/vwtfzhcL/1/ ] looking something like this one ?? Don't worry about the border I just make it for understanding

Comment: So it's ok to add a class to rows and add some margin? I was not sure if this is the right thing to do in Bootstrap...

Comment: Yes it's a good Idea to make some extra useful class like this. you can create a class .nopadding{padding: 0;} and use it somewhere  you don't want padding. there is many more you can create

Comment: If you're familiar with CSS preprocessors, you can change the gutter widths between columns (it's a variable) then regenerate the Bootstrap CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "answer" of mine should really be a comment; however, I don't have enough rep.

For an answer, yes, give the divs with the `row` class another class, probably something like this, spacing the top and bottom of each 10px:

`.part {
   margin: 10px 0; 
}`

An important thing to think about when using frameworks like bootstrap is that it isn't the end of the world if you modify the components or spacing or something. Some things won't look like you want them to; just give them extra classes, or if you are desperate, use the `!important` flag. It was built on the same technology, after all.

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap 5 I add g-0 to g-5 class with row class to add space around each col.
EX.

```
<div class="row g-3">
 <div class="col">...</div>
 <div class="col">...</div>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/

Comment: This answer could be more helpful with a small example.

Comment: done. kindly check if its understandable. thank u

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*you can create your own custom css for use here is some example*/
.border {
  border: 1px solid red; /* just to make sure space between blocks*/
}

.margin-top {
  margin-top: 5px; 
}
   
.nopad{
 padding:0 ; 
}
div[class*='spacer-'] { display: block; }
.spacer-mini { height: 20px; }
.spacer-small { height: 40px; }
.spacer-medium { height: 60px; }
.spacer-big { height: 100px; }
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="main_content">
  <div class="row border margin-top">
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">text1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row border  margin-top">
<div class="col-md-12">text2</div>
  </div>

<div class="spacer-mini"></div> <!-- Using Spacer-Mini and avoiding the margin top -->

  <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 border">part1</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 border">part2</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```